# Size of Strings and Calendar Objects Java

Tags: java, calendar

I am doing some basic (edit: reading and writing to a txt file), which requires me to store a bunch of expenses, and their attributes (i.e. name, price, date of purchase, etc.) I would like to be able to compare dates of purchases if possible. It occured to me that I had a few options when it came to what type of object the date of purchase should be:

- I could make the date a Calendar object, and store it on the .txt this would mean storing lots of Calendar objects at once, and then easily compare the dates
- I could make the date a String, store it, transmute it to a Calendar object, and then compare them
- I could leave the dates as strings and when I am ready to compare them, create some kind of code to go through individual characters and pick out a certain phrase or set of characters.

Which of these would probably be best for keeping the load on the computer down? Also, how would you go about loading objects as they build up over time? Once a person has a lot of spending, it would get pretty hefty to load every single item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly suggest using [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) wherever possible, rather than `Calendar` and `Date` - it's a *much* cleaner date/time API.

Beyond that, *definitely* make your object model match your domain as closely as possible. You're dealing with dates, not strings - so make your object model reflect that. You should be converting between strings and dates as rarely as possible. It not clear what you mean by "store it on the .txt" (given that elsewhere you're talking about a database) but using JDBC you'd use parameters anyway, without string conversions.

As for load - work out your performance requirements beforehand, try the simplest approach that works, and test whether that meets your requirements. Usually when people talk about having to have an efficient solution they haven't actually considered what they need. You talk about it getting "pretty hefty" to load every single item - how many items? Can you load them in a batch? Where will the database be? You'd be amazed how much data *can* be processed these days - but you need to understand the parameters of your problem before you make too many decisions that are hard to change later.

Comment: I think I misused the term database. What I meant was, I'm just writing the data for each item to a text file, and then reading from it, and putting each item onto a list. I want the program to be able to run well even if the user has made hundreds or thousands of transactions. By loading them in batches, I am guessing you mean load a certain number at a time, and if more are needed, load more?

Comment: @comscis: You'd need to say more about your actual use cases - and if you're worried about performance, you should strongly consider using some kind of databases. But frankly, "thousands" of records should load in the blink of an eye anyway.

Comment: Okay, that should be plenty. It's a project, but I do want it to be robust, and not purely academic. As for the actual cases, each item consists of 3 Strings, an int, a double, and now at your recommendation a Calendar object, with a handful of methods, and setters and getters for each.

Comment: @comscis: No, my recommendation wasn't `Calendar` - it was to use Joda Time. Being "robust" doesn't mean "make it optimized to the hilt at the expense of simplicity" - different approaches are appropriate for different scales. The storage and representation you would use for a smallish system is not necessarily the one you'd use for a billion users. I'm more concerned about your use of `double` though - if that's for a currency amount, you should use `BigDecimal`, or use `int` as the number of pence/cents/whatever. `double` is not appropriate for financial quantities.

Comment: I will look into Joda Time :) as for the double, yeah it probably would be best to switch to BigDecimal. I'll take that into consideration as well. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @comscis, Joda Time has a (small) learning curve that is worth climbing. A lot easier (and stable) than `Calendar`.